# Android studio app crashing error : AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Tags: java, android

i have made a android app which when testing in the emulator crashes whenever i am trying to apply coupon code. i am so confused and i am unable to figure out the error . here are my logs of the android app :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.dhruv.shop, PID: 1790
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "1,2,11"
        at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
        at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:410)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:367)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
        at com.dhruv.shop.fragments.Checkout.applyCoupon(Checkout.java:1760)
        at com.dhruv.shop.fragments.Checkout$26.onResponse(Checkout.java:1573)
        at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 1790 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

and i figured out that my error code is pointing towards applycoupon method in checkout.java file ,can anyone figure out whats causing the error in the below code and give me the solution to this error as soon as possible ,  so here is my the code which is causing error :

```
public void applyCoupon(CouponsInfo coupon) {

    double discount = 0.0;

    if (coupon.getDiscountType().equalsIgnoreCase("fixed_cart")) {
        discount = Double.parseDouble(coupon.getAmount());

    }
    else if (coupon.getDiscountType().equalsIgnoreCase("percent")) {
        discount = (checkoutSubtotal * Double.parseDouble(coupon.getAmount())) / 100;

    }
    else if (coupon.getDiscountType().equalsIgnoreCase("fixed_product")) {

        for (int i=0;  i<checkoutItemsList.size();  i++) {

            int productID = checkoutItemsList.get(i).getCustomersBasketProduct().getProductsId();
            int categoryID = Integer.parseInt(checkoutItemsList.get(i).getCustomersBasketProduct().getCategoryIDs());


            if (!checkoutItemsList.get(i).getCustomersBasketProduct().getIsSaleProduct().equalsIgnoreCase("1")  ||  !coupon.getExcludeSaleItems().equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                if (!isStringExistsInList(String.valueOf(categoryID), coupon.getExcludedProductCategories())  ||  coupon.getExcludedProductCategories().size() == 0 ) {
                    if (!isStringExistsInList(String.valueOf(productID), coupon.getExcludeProductIds())  ||  coupon.getExcludeProductIds().size() == 0 ) {
                        if (isStringExistsInList(String.valueOf(categoryID), coupon.getProductCategories())  ||  coupon.getProductCategories().size() == 0 ) {
                            if (isStringExistsInList(String.valueOf(productID), coupon.getProductIds())  ||  coupon.getProductIds().size() == 0 ) {

                                discount += (Double.parseDouble(coupon.getAmount()) * checkoutItemsList.get(i).getCustomersBasketProduct().getCustomersBasketQuantity());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


        }

    }
    else if (coupon.getDiscountType().equalsIgnoreCase("percent_product")) {

        for (int i=0;  i<checkoutItemsList.size();  i++) {

            int productID = checkoutItemsList.get(i).getCustomersBasketProduct().getProductsId();

                String categoryID = checkoutItemsList.get(i).getCustomersBasketProduct().getCategoryIDs();
                if (!checkoutItemsList.get(i).getCustomersBasketProduct().getIsSaleProduct().equalsIgnoreCase("1")  ||  !coupon.getExcludeSaleItems().equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                    if (!isStringExistsInList(categoryID, coupon.getExcludedProductCategories())  ||  coupon.getExcludedProductCategories().size() == 0 ) {
                        if (!isStringExistsInList(String.valueOf(productID), coupon.getExcludeProductIds())  ||  coupon.getExcludeProductIds().size() == 0 ) {
                            if (isStringExistsInList(categoryID, coupon.getProductCategories())  ||  coupon.getProductCategories().size() == 0 ) {
                                if (isStringExistsInList(String.valueOf(productID), coupon.getProductIds())  ||  coupon.getProductIds().size() == 0 ) {

                                    double discountOnPrice = (Double.parseDouble(checkoutItemsList.get(i).getCustomersBasketProduct().getProductsFinalPrice()) * Double.parseDouble(coupon.getAmount())) / 100;
                                    discount += (discountOnPrice * checkoutItemsList.get(i).getCustomersBasketProduct().getCustomersBasketQuantity());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }



        }
    }

    if ((checkoutDiscount+discount) >= getProductsSubTotal()) {
        showSnackBarForCoupon(getString(R.string.coupon_cannot_be_applied));
    }
    else {
        if (coupon.getIndividualUse().equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
            couponsList.clear();
            checkoutDiscount = 0.0;
            checkoutShipping = checkoutShippingCost;
            disableOtherCoupons = true;
            setCheckoutTotal();
        }

        if (coupon.getFreeShipping().equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
            checkoutShipping = 0.0;
        }


        checkoutDiscount += discount;
        coupon.setDiscount(String.valueOf(discount));


        couponsList.add(coupon);
        checkout_coupon_code.setText("");
        couponsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        setCheckoutTotal();
    }

}
```

line no. 1760 of checkout.java is :

```
int categoryID = Integer.parseInt(checkoutItemsList.get(i).getCustomersBasketProduct().getCategoryIDs());
```

another useful method :

```
 private void proceedOrder() {
        // Formate to minimum two digit end
        NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
        formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
        formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        PostOrder orderDetails = new PostOrder();
        List<PostProducts> orderProductList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i=0;  i<checkoutItemsList.size();  i++) {

            PostProducts orderProduct = new PostProducts();

            String str = ""+checkoutItemsList.get(i).getCustomersBasketProduct().getCategoryIDs();
            // Get current Product Details
            orderProduct.setProductsId(checkoutItemsList.get(i).getCustomersBasketProduct().getProductsId());
            orderProduct.setProductsName(checkoutItemsList.get(i).getCustomersBasketProduct().getProductsName());
            orderProduct.setModel(checkoutItemsList.get(i).getCustomersBasketProduct().getProductsModel());
            orderProduct.setImage(checkoutItemsList.get(i).getCustomersBasketProduct().getProductsImage());
            orderProduct.setWeight(checkoutItemsList.get(i).getCustomersBasketProduct().getProductsWeight());
            orderProduct.setUnit(checkoutItemsList.get(i).getCustomersBasketProduct().getProductsWeightUnit());
            orderProduct.setManufacture(checkoutItemsList.get(i).getCustomersBasketProduct().getManufacturersName());
            orderProduct.setCategoriesId(""+checkoutItemsList.get(i).getCustomersBasketProduct().getCategoryIDs());
            orderProduct.setCategoriesName(checkoutItemsList.get(i).getCustomersBasketProduct().getCategoryNames());
            orderProduct.setPrice(formatter.format(Double.parseDouble(checkoutItemsList.get(i).getCustomersBasketProduct().getProductsPrice())));
            orderProduct.setFinalPrice(formatter.format(Double.parseDouble(checkoutItemsList.get(i).getCustomersBasketProduct().getProductsFinalPrice())));
            orderProduct.setSubtotal(formatter.format(Double.parseDouble(checkoutItemsList.get(i).getCustomersBasketProduct().getTotalPrice())));
            orderProduct.setTotal(formatter.format(Double.parseDouble(checkoutItemsList.get(i).getCustomersBasketProduct().getTotalPrice())));
            orderProduct.setCustomersBasketQuantity(checkoutItemsList.get(i).getCustomersBasketProduct().getCustomersBasketQuantity());

            orderProduct.setOnSale(checkoutItemsList.get(i).getCustomersBasketProduct().getIsSaleProduct().equalsIgnoreCase("1"));


            List<PostProductsAttributes> productAttributes = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int j=0;  j<checkoutItemsList.get(i).getCustomersBasketProductAttributes().size();  j++) {
                CartProductAttributes cartProductAttributes = checkoutItemsList.get(i).getCustomersBasketProductAttributes().get(j);
                Option attributeOption = cartProductAttributes.getOption();
                Value attributeValue = cartProductAttributes.getValues().get(0);

                PostProductsAttributes attribute = new PostProductsAttributes();
                attribute.setProductsOptionsId(String.valueOf(attributeOption.getId()));
                attribute.setProductsOptions(attributeOption.getName());
                attribute.setProductsOptionsValuesId(String.valueOf(attributeValue.getId()));
                attribute.setProductsOptionsValues(attributeValue.getValue());
                attribute.setOptionsValuesPrice(attributeValue.getPrice());
                attribute.setPricePrefix(attributeValue.getPricePrefix());
                attribute.setAttributeName(attributeValue.getValue()+" "+attributeValue.getPricePrefix()+attributeValue.getPrice());
                attribute.setOrdersProductsAttributesId(String.valueOf(attributeValue.getProducts_attributes_id()));
                productAttributes.add(attribute);
            }

            orderProduct.setAttributes(productAttributes);


            // Add current Product to orderProductList
            orderProductList.add(orderProduct);
        }


        // Set Customer Info
        orderDetails.setCustomersId(Integer.parseInt(userInfo.getCustomersId()));
        orderDetails.setCustomersName(userInfo.getCustomersFirstname());
        orderDetails.setCustomersTelephone(userInfo.getCustomersTelephone());
        orderDetails.setCustomersEmailAddress(userInfo.getCustomersEmailAddress());

        // Set Shipping  Info
        orderDetails.setDeliveryFirstname(shippingAddress.getFirstname());
        orderDetails.setDeliveryLastname(shippingAddress.getLastname());
        orderDetails.setDeliveryStreetAddress(shippingAddress.getStreet());
        orderDetails.setDeliveryPostcode(shippingAddress.getPostcode());
        orderDetails.setDeliverySuburb(shippingAddress.getSuburb());
        orderDetails.setDeliveryCity(shippingAddress.getCity());
        orderDetails.setDeliveryZone(shippingAddress.getZoneName());
        orderDetails.setDeliveryState(shippingAddress.getZoneName());
        orderDetails.setDeliverySuburb(shippingAddress.getZoneName());
        orderDetails.setDeliveryCountry(shippingAddress.getCountryName());
        orderDetails.setDeliveryZoneId(String.valueOf(shippingAddress.getZoneId()));
        orderDetails.setDeliveryCountryId(String.valueOf(shippingAddress.getCountriesId()));
        orderDetails.setDeliveryPhone(String.valueOf(shippingAddress.getDeliveryPhone()));


        // Set Billing Info
        orderDetails.setBillingFirstname(billingAddress.getFirstname());
        orderDetails.setBillingLastname(billingAddress.getLastname());
        orderDetails.setBillingStreetAddress(billingAddress.getStreet());
        orderDetails.setBillingPostcode(billingAddress.getPostcode());
        orderDetails.setBillingSuburb(billingAddress.getSuburb());
        orderDetails.setBillingCity(billingAddress.getCity());
        orderDetails.setBillingZone(billingAddress.getZoneName());
        orderDetails.setBillingState(billingAddress.getZoneName());
        orderDetails.setBillingSuburb(billingAddress.getZoneName());
        orderDetails.setBillingCountry(billingAddress.getCountryName());
        orderDetails.setBillingZoneId(String.valueOf(billingAddress.getZoneId()));
        orderDetails.setBillingCountryId(String.valueOf(billingAddress.getCountriesId()));
        orderDetails.setBillingPhone(String.valueOf(billingAddress.getDeliveryPhone()));

        orderDetails.setLanguage_id(ConstantValues.LANGUAGE_ID);

        orderDetails.setTaxZoneId(shippingAddress.getZoneId());
        orderDetails.setTotalTax(Double.parseDouble(formatter.format(checkoutTotal)));
        orderDetails.setShippingCost(Double.parseDouble(formatter.format(checkoutShipping)));
        orderDetails.setShippingMethod(shippingMethod.getName());

        orderDetails.setComments(checkout_comments.getText().toString().trim());

        if (couponsList.size() > 0) {
            orderDetails.setIsCouponApplied(1);
        } else {
            orderDetails.setIsCouponApplied(0);
        }
        orderDetails.setCouponAmount(Double.parseDouble(formatter.format(checkoutDiscount)));
        orderDetails.setCoupons(couponsList);

        Log.d("Nonce",paymentNonceToken);
        // Set PaymentNonceToken and PaymentMethod
        orderDetails.setNonce(paymentNonceToken);
        orderDetails.setPaymentMethod(selectedPaymentMethod);

        // Set Checkout Price and Products
        orderDetails.setProductsTotal(Double.parseDouble(formatter.format(checkoutSubtotal)));
        orderDetails.setTotalPrice(Double.parseDouble(formatter.format(checkoutTotal)));
        orderDetails.setProducts(orderProductList);


        PlaceOrderNow(orderDetails);

    }
```

Comment: Which line throws the `Exception`? Why have you applied parsing in `Double.parseDouble(coupon.getAmount()) * checkoutItemsList.get(i).getCustomersBasketProduct().getCustomersBasketQuantity())`? As far as I can see, you are trying to parse the result of a multiplication, which is unlikely to be a `String`, maybe it is an `int`, however, you won't need that parsing, will you?.

Comment: post yur java class Checkout.java:1760 line number 1760

Comment: `int categoryID = Integer.parseInt...` this line throws the error I guess, your category id is given `1,2,11`, which shouldn't have any commas. maybe it is a list of category ids, instead one

Comment: `  else {
        if (coupon.getIndividualUse().equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
            couponsList.clear();
            checkoutDiscount = 0.0;
            checkoutShipping = checkoutShippingCost;
            disableOtherCoupons = true;
            setCheckoutTotal();
        }

        if (coupon.getFreeShipping().equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
            checkoutShipping = 0.0;
        }` You are using the same INT here IE 1 and the  period can also cause an issue

Comment: The `Exception` seems to be caused by `Integer.parseInt(checkoutItemsList.get(i).getCustomersBasketProduct().getCategoryIDs());`, because the error message states *Invalid int: "1,2,11"* while the actual result looks like a *list of IDs*, which corresponds to the method name `getCategoryIDs()`.

Comment: @KaushalPanchal updated in the question

Comment: @deHaar can you provide a solution for this

Comment: check getCustomersBasketProduct().getCategoryIDs() data receive in which datatype and which datatype you are passing

Comment: Post your model class

Comment: @KaushalPanchal the model class would be too big , should i post it ??

Comment: Give the return type of `getCustomersBasketProduct()` a method that returns only a single id as `int` or parse the list of the currently used method, but how would you find the correct ID in a list of IDs?

Comment: post getCustomersBasketProduct().getCategoryIDs() line of model class

Comment: @deHaar its numeric value

Comment: @KaushalPanchal i have updated the question , pasted some code check mout

Comment: @deHaar i have pasted some udeful code related getcatagoriesid , now please help me solve this error

Comment: I was talking about `getCategoryIds()`, which seems to be different from `getCategoriesID()`... Sorry, but your code is a really good example for confusion caused by unclear naming of methods (at least). Could you show us the method `getCategoryIds()` (from whatever class) and explain what you exactly want to do with that method. Be as exact as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First **convert** the `String` data to *only* `numeric` string using `replaceAll` and then parse the numeric string data like :-

```
Integer.parseInt(stringData.replaceAll(",","")); // this should avoid the crash !
```

But to get the list of category id u should use `split` by `,` like :-

```
String[] categoryIds = checkoutItemsList.get(i).getCustomersBasketProduct().getCategoryIDs().split(",");
```

**Then convert the string array to int array**

```
int[] intIds = Arrays.stream(categoryIds).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

Comment: where should i post this line in the code , sorry i am a beginer so unable to figure out

Comment: ya it worked , the movement i tryed it by the string category id one , it worked (i didnt need to convert string array to int array)